# Azure Dev Ops: Unable to determine the Source Control Server

Tags: visual-studio, server, azure-devops, mapping, source-control-bindings

In the command prompt, I am typing:

```
tf workfold /unmap /workspace:xxx dev.azure.com/xxx/Mace
```

as I try to remove a project from an organization.

I also try:

```
tf workfold /unmap /workspace:xxx dev.azure.com/yyy/Mace
```

In both cases, I am getting:

> Unable to determine the Source Control Server

substituting the computer name for `dev.azure.com/xxx` didn't help, either.

`xxx` is the development organization, `yyy` is for production.

I went the `tf.exe` route because I kept on getting:

> The path c:\wsg_winservices\WinApps\Mace is already mapped in workspace xxx

Nothing helped here as I used `TF.Exe` as a last resort for removing a project from a workspace:

1. I deleted the source control files and source control folders in my local project.
2. I removed the **TeamFoundation** stuff in the solution using notepad.
3. I changed the project name in `xxx` (`dev.azure.com`) and then deleted it.
4. Unbind didn't work, mapping to local folder didn't work, removing the workspace didn't work, changing the location from local to server didn't work.

How do you solve this?  How do you remove the mapping from workspace `xxx`?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Can you delete project now? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

To remove a project from an organization,you can try to use [Projects - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}?api-version=5.1
```

To get project id , use [Projects - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) rest api.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1
```

From the response , you can get projectId:

Sample:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1",
      "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
      "description": "Team Foundation Version Control projects.",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1",
      "state": "wellFormed"
    },
...
}
```

Comment: This makes it even more confusing!!!! What do you mean by an instance, collection and project id?  All I did was create a project in dev.azure.com under the organization of xxx.  There is a project name but no id, it never asked me for a collection or an instance.  I created the project for Team Foundation rather than Git (in visual studio) and uploaded it to my xxx organization where I can see the files and the folders just fine for the project!!!!  Where does this collection, instance and project id come from????

Comment: The example I gave earlier is about azure devops server (TFS), now I have updated the answer. For azure devops service, please see my update, which shows how to get the projectId.